# Using PHP variable in javascript for Google Maps polygon

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I'm drawing a polygon on a Google map using a set of coordinates pulled from a database.

- map.php pulls the coordinates from the database
- scripts.js creates the map on document ready and stores all of the map config options

Boundary coordinates string example:

```
[52.6294414232, 1.28337337354], [52.6294108159, 1.28350410559], [52.6293577844, 1.28347057106], [52.6292373999, 1.28391974753], [52.6293340783, 1.28400089488], [52.6292540937, 1.28429051171], [52.6292088096, 1.28430189851], [52.6291929061, 1.2842268041], [52.6291753654, 1.28421070907], [52.6291251702, 1.28439909373], [52.6289228389, 1.28423612589], [52.6289538563, 1.28409064607], [52.628795581, 1.28396054235], [52.6288674082, 1.28364075593], [52.628946546, 1.28370580721], [52.6289763352, 1.28360457624], [52.6290289574, 1.2836528604], [52.6290693582, 1.28349330243], [52.6291215713, 1.2835563364], [52.6292403179, 1.28316615953],
```

I know the coordinate string is valid as when I enter this manually into the map javascript, the polygon shows correctly.

I'm storing the coordinate string in PHP variable `$boundary`, then trying to pass it through to be used in javascript with the following in map.php:

```
<script>
var boundary = <?php echo $boundary ?>;
</script>
```

Using `console.log(boundary)` in scripts.js logs the coordinate string properly in the console - meaning the variable is accessible from the js file - but the map won't draw the polygon and errors with "Uncaught InvalidValueError: at index 0: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object".

However, if I place all of the scripts.js in map.php wrapped in script tags, then `<?php echo $boundary ?>`, the polygon renders perfectly. This suggests that passing the variable from PHP to javascript is what's causing the problem.

I've tried cleaning the output using

```
var boundary = <?php echo json_encode($boundary) ?>;
```

but with no success.

Can anybody suggest a method of passing this coordinate string across that will render out properly in the map javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You must convert the Number-pairs to `google.maps.LatLng`'s before you assign `boundary` to the `path`-property of the map.

```
var boundary = <?php echo $boundary; ?>;

for(var i = 0; i < boundary.length; ++i ){
  boundary[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(boundary[i][0], 
                                       boundary[i][1]);
}
new google.maps.Polygon({path:boundary/*,more properties*/});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if so, why does entering the same string manually or echoing the $boundary var in PHP work, yet not in javascript? They should be three methods of doing the exact same thing?

Comment: what works in PHP? the maps-API is a javascript-library.

Comment: If I dump the contents of the javascript in script tags in the php file and run it from there, it draws the polygon perfectly. The issue seems to be passing the string/variable from PHP to javascript.

Comment: I don't know what exactly  you dump there, but I'm sure it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have problems trying to excute PHP statements between <SCRIPT> tags. Try this:

```
<? print
"<script language=javascript>
   var boundary = $boundary
</script>"
?>
```

(formatted to your liking)